Created an app with Pyinstaller on Mac, the app doesn't work but the shell file does. Why?
I am creating an app that generates a schedule for my school. Here is the python code for it:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import json
import logging
import datetime
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='app.log', filemode='w',
                    format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  
PREFERENCES_FILE = os.path.join(application_path, "user_preferences.json")

def save_preferences(data):
    try:
        with open(PREFERENCES_FILE, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
        logging.info("Preferences saved successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to save preferences: {e}")
      
def load_preferences():
    try:
        if os.path.exists(PREFERENCES_FILE):
            with open(PREFERENCES_FILE, 'r') as f:
                return json.load(f)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error reading preferences: {e}")
    return None

def delete_preferences():
    try:
        if os.path.exists(PREFERENCES_FILE):
            os.remove(PREFERENCES_FILE)
            logging.info("Preferences deleted successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to delete preferences: {e}")
      
def show_schedule(day, preferences):
    schedule = preferences['schedule']
    day_schedule = schedule.get(day, [])
    schedule_text = f"Schedule for {day}:\n"
    for time_range, subject_key in day_schedule:
        subject = preferences['subjects'].get(subject_key, "Free")
        schedule_text += f"{time_range} - {subject}\n"
    schedule_label.config(text=schedule_text)
  
def setup_preferences():
    def save_and_close():
        subjects = {
            'MESH1': mesh1_var.get(),
            'MESH2': mesh2_var.get(),
            'MESH3': mesh3_var.get(),
            'MESH4': mesh4_var.get(),
            'WL': wl_var.get(),
            'WELLNESS': 'Wellness',
            'ELECTIVE1': elective1_entry.get(),
            'ELECTIVE2': elective2_entry.get(),
            'CLUB': club_entry.get(),
            'GEOMETRY': 'Geometry' if geometry_var.get() else None,
            'RECESS': 'Recess',
            'LUNCH': 'Lunch',
            'ACADEMIC_COACHING': 'Academic Coaching',
            'ADVISORY': 'Advisory'
        }
        preferences = {
            'subjects': subjects,
            'schedule': load_default_schedule(geometry_var.get())
        }
        save_preferences(preferences)
        setup_root.destroy()
        main_app()
      
    setup_root = tk.Tk()
    setup_root.title("Setup Preferences")
  
    mesh_options = ["Math", "English", "Science", "History"]
    wl_options = ["Spanish", "French", "FOL"]
    mesh1_var, mesh2_var, mesh3_var, mesh4_var, wl_var = tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar()
    geometry_var = tk.BooleanVar()
  
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select MESH1:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=mesh1_var, values=mesh_options).pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select MESH2:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=mesh2_var, values=mesh_options).pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select MESH3:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=mesh3_var, values=mesh_options).pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select MESH4:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=mesh4_var, values=mesh_options).pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select WL:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=wl_var, values=wl_options).pack()
  
    ttk.Checkbutton(setup_root, text="Include Geometry", variable=geometry_var).pack()
  
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Enter AM ICE:").pack()
    elective1_entry = ttk.Entry(setup_root)
    elective1_entry.pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Enter PM ICE:").pack()
    elective2_entry = ttk.Entry(setup_root)
    elective2_entry.pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Enter Club:").pack()
    club_entry = ttk.Entry(setup_root)
    club_entry.pack()
  
    ttk.Button(setup_root, text="Save and Start", command=save_and_close).pack(pady=10)
    setup_root.mainloop()
  
def load_default_schedule(include_geometry):
    today = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()  # Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6
    geometry_days = [0, 2, 4]  # Monday, Wednesday, Friday
  
    schedule = {
        'A': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "CLUB"), ("9:20-10:10", "MESH1"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH3"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH2"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "WL"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH4"), ("2:20-3:10", "ELECTIVE2")],
        'B': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ELECTIVE1"), ("9:20-10:10", "WL"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH2"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH3"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "MESH4"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH1"), ("2:20-3:10", "ELECTIVE2")],
        'C': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ACADEMIC_COACHING"), ("9:20-10:10", "MESH2"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH4"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH1"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "WL"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH3"), ("2:20-3:10", "ELECTIVE2")],
        'D': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ELECTIVE1"), ("9:20-10:10", "WL"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH4"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH1"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "MESH3"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH2"), ("2:20-3:10", "ACADEMIC_COACHING")],
        'E': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ELECTIVE1"), ("9:20-10:10", "MESH1"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH3"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH2"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "WELLNESS"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH4"), ("2:20-3:10", "ELECTIVE2")],
        'F': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ELECTIVE1"), ("9:20-10:10", "WL"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH2"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH3"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "MESH4"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH1"), ("2:20-3:10", "ACADEMIC_COACHING")]
    }
  
    if include_geometry and today in geometry_days:
        geometry_class = ("7:00-8:00", "GEOMETRY")
        for key in schedule:
            schedule[key].insert(0, geometry_class)
          
    return schedule

def main_app():
    preferences = load_preferences()
    if not preferences:
        setup_preferences()
        return
  
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("School Schedule")
  
    day_var = tk.StringVar(value='A')
    day_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=day_var, values=list('ABCDEF'))
    day_dropdown.pack(pady=10)
  
    show_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Show Schedule", command=lambda: show_schedule(day_var.get(), preferences))
    show_button.pack(pady=5)
  
    reset_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Reset Preferences", command=lambda: [delete_preferences(), root.destroy(), setup_preferences()])
    reset_button.pack(pady=5)
  
    global schedule_label
    schedule_label = tk.Label(root, text="", justify=tk.LEFT)
    schedule_label.pack(pady=10)
  
    root.mainloop()
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_app()
  

I tried to create the program on my Mac using this command:
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=/Users/jacob/\ icon.iconset/857457.icns --name="School Schedule App" /Users/jacob/School_Schedule_App.py
When I tried to open the app by double clicking it, nothing happened. However, if I went into the package contents and then the MacOS folder, running the shell script would open the app and make it run normally. Why is this, and how can I make it so that it runs just by opening the app normally?
Thank you, and if you have any follow-up questions, let me know, and I will do my best to answer them.

If the preferences file doesn't already exist (which is certainly going to be the case on the first run of the program), you never assign a value to preferences inside main_app() - but you try to use it in a couple of places.

@jasonharper Sure, but what should I do about it? Thanks

The log directory of the app should use the complete directory：
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='app.log', filemode='w',
                    format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

====》
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='/Users/hodge/Desktop/code_demo/python/build/app.log', filemode='w',
                    format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


I want this script to work on all computers eg. You would download it and run it as a .app file. Is it possible to make it so that it just creates the file in a resources folder of the app, and the user doesn't need to do anything? Thanks

can use os api do it:
os.makedirs(directory)
or
try:
with open('example.txt', 'x') as file:
file.write("Hello, World!")
except FileExistsError:
print("File is Exists")
